# Python numpy - string representation of a matrix to 2D numpy array while keeping formatting and feed it to NetworkX

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, networkx

I need some help with my code. I have txt files in the following format (2 samples):

```
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
w...o.xx.o......o..xoxx..w
w...oooooo........o..o...w
w....xxx.........o.oxoo.ow
wx...............oxo...oow
wwwwwwwwww........o...wxxw
wb ...co..............wxxw
w  ........Ao....o....wxxw
wooo............. ....w..w
w......x....wwwwx x.oow..w
wc  .....x..ooxxo ....w..w
w   ..E..........b     ..w
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
```

and

```
wwwwwwwwwwwww
w........w..w
w...1.......w
w...A.1.w.0ww
www.w1..wwwww
w.......w.0.w
w.1........ww
w..........ww
wwwwwwwwwwwww
```

What I want to do is read all the files in the folder (there's maybe about 10 of these txt files),  change all chars to 0 except for the character "w" and "A", these will be 1 and 2.

I managed to figure this part out, here's my partial solution:

```
import glob
import os
import re
import numpy as np
import ast
import networkx as nx
def create_matrix_from_layout(folder):
    files = glob.glob(folder)
    file_set = {}
    for f in files:
        fname = os.path.basename(f)
        with open(f, "r") as tmp:
            tmp_data = tmp.read()
        tmp_data = re.sub(r"[^wA\n]", r"0", tmp_data)
        tmp_data = tmp_data.replace("w", "1").replace("A", "2")
        arr = np.array(tmp_data)
        #print(arr.ndim)
        print(arr)
        #G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(arr)
        #print(G)

create_matrix_from_layout("layouts/*.txt")
```

Here's the output (sample):

```
111111111111111111111111
111100001000110000000111
100000101000000011000011
100000000011002011100001
101111011111000011000111
100000000100000000000011
110001000000110001110001
110000110001111000010001
111000000000000001000001
111111000000111111000011
```

All looks well, but here is where the problem begins. I need to feed it to NetworkX and create a graph that would consist of vertices (of 1s) and edges connecting them.

Obviously, my data structure is not something NetworkX wants to work with, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to do it better.

```
NetworkXError: Input array must be 2D, not 0
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Is that an adjacency matrix? Also, what does 2 mean? Is it the weight of the edge?

Comment: Hey Riccardo, what I tried to do is basically encode the layouts (first 2 code samples) into a matrix. The 0, 1, 2 I would say are ID's. Basically what I want to do is connect every "node" that has a value of 1 to other 1s, "2" can be disregarded for now. If it would be possible to know/show the distances in networkx between the 1s, that would be great too.

Comment: So, is this an adjacency matrix?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's quite that. Imagine it as a layout of a computer game map, where 1s are walls, 0s is floor and 2 is your controllable character. Does that help? Would it be any simpler if I just removed the "2", as it's not really important for me right now? Then I'd assume it could be an adjacency matrix.

Comment: What would you expect the graph to look like (maybe for an easy example)?

Comment: It would be ideal if you could provide an input (a simple one) and the expected output

Comment: Each "1" would be a node in an undirected weighted graph connected by edges to all the other 1s. EDIT: let me try to get you an example.

Comment: I tried sketching something, hope it clarifies my question. [link to imgur](https://imgur.com/dHPmJRK) @Riccardo Bucco
First graph is incomplete because it would make things hard to see. I hope it's more clear though.

Comment: Tbh it would be plenty of help to me if i could just parse it right and feed it to networkx. I can probably play around with it after that on my own. I'm mainly just having trouble with the data structure.

Comment: why all 1s are connected? why not only adjacent 1s? Like in a grid graph

Comment: Sure, that would work for me as well. Whichever solution is easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a grid graph, and then remove all nodes where you have a zero. In this way you will have a graph in which there is a node for each '1' in your matrix, and adjacent 1s are connected.

```
from itertools import product

import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

coor = np.array(list(product(*map(range, arr.shape))))
G = nx.grid_2d_graph(*arr.shape)
G.remove_nodes_from(map(tuple, coor[arr.flatten() == 0]))
```

Here the assumption is that `arr` is a numpy array containing 1 or 0. Here is an example:

```
>>> arr
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
>>> coor = np.array(list(product(*map(range, arr.shape))))
>>> G = nx.grid_2d_graph(*arr.shape)
>>> G.remove_nodes_from(map(tuple, coor[arr.flatten() == 0]))
>>> G.nodes
NodeView(((0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4),
          (1, 0), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4),
          (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)))
>>> G.edges
EdgeView([((0, 0), (1, 0)), ((0, 0), (0, 1)), ((0, 1), (0, 2)),
          ((0, 2), (0, 3)), ((0, 3), (1, 3)), ((0, 3), (0, 4)),
          ((1, 3), (2, 3)), ((2, 2), (3, 2)), ((2, 2), (2, 3)),
          ((2, 3), (3, 3)), ((2, 3), (2, 4)), ((2, 4), (3, 4)),
          ((3, 0), (3, 1)), ((3, 1), (3, 2)), ((3, 2), (3, 3)),
          ((3, 3), (3, 4))])
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution. It seems like in my case "coor" is an empty list and nx.grid_2d_graph throws out an error: `TypeError: argmap_grid_2d_graph_5() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'm' and 'n'`

Maybe it has something to do with my "arr" for some reason having dim = 0?

Comment: @Pehy Yes, `arr` might be wrong. Have you checked it?

Comment: Well thats part of the problem I'm having, I'm not sure I'm parsing it correctly. It does have 0 dimensions. Please, refer to my code in the question post.

Comment: @Pehy Your `create_matrix_from_layout` function is already creating a numpy array, why can't you simply use that one?

Comment: Yes, that's the one I'm using. Would you mind checking further, where the culprit is? [code](https://pastebin.com/CBbA4C9N), and [sample txt to load](https://pastebin.com/81H8Cq6M). Please, give it a try. I think I'm creating the array wrong.

Comment: Managed to make it work. Your code works! It was indeed a problem in my array. Needed to do some hacks to make numpy take it. Marking as solved.